# Initial navigation view controller of AuthUI not working under Xcode 10.2

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, swift5, xcode10.2

I recently upgraded to Xcode 10.2.
Before the upgrade I could use the stock Initial Navigation View Controller of AuthUI from Firebase Realtime Database, I could sign up and login to Firebase without problems, now I get a "welcome" screen only.
I'm using the same code as before. (note that the authentification works in my old project even with Xcode 10.2, I cannot make any new projects using the Initial Navigation View Controller of AuthUI)

I tried the same code that worked with Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2
I even set up another test project from zero to diagnose the problem, I reached out to the Firebase team about this, I'm posting my question here in the meantime, hoping for a fast answer.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
        guard authUI != nil else { return }
        authUI?.delegate = self
        let authViewController = (authUI?.authViewController())!
        present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}

extension ViewController: FUIAuthDelegate {
    func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {
        guard error == nil else { return }
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goHome", sender: self)
    }
}
```

The problem is that the authentification page won't load up, I cannot sign up/login; therefore the performSegue never fires.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code :

```
        authUI?.providers = [FUIEmailAuth()]
```

Plus, you have modify the pod file and add: pod 'FirebaseUI/Email' if you are using email.